# Single word or brief phrase for "people started using this product due to my presentation"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I want to write about the following achievement in my resume: I made presentations on a certain software X, which led to 10 people deciding to start using it.

This is the first draft of my sentence.

> - Presented effective use of software X on Y-type projects, **leading to 10 people starting to use it.**

(X and Y are placeholders, by the way.)

The phrase in bold doesn't seem good. I would like a word or phrase to make it sound more "catchy". The only word I could think of was *adopting* as in: "... leading to 10 people adopting it."

However, *adopting* still doesn't sound good enough. While it does get thrown around a lot at my current workplace, I do not know if it would be interpreted in the same way everywhere.

Is there a somewhat more generally understood word or phrase that expresses the above idea?

Comment: Just to be clear, I did briefly consider asking this question on Workplace.SE but then decided that it is more English-centric than resume-centric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the use of strong and descriptive words here, while removing the unnecessary.

What did your presentation do to the 10 people? *Define* their end state.

Here is my take:

> - Presented effective use of software X on Y-type projects,
>     **convincing** 10 people to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the phrasing sounds awkward because of the two *-ing* words in such close proximity.

You could overcome this by simply using a semi-colon:

> Presented effective use of software X on Y-type projects; 10 people started using it.
>   Presented effective use of software X on Y-type projects; 10 people adopted it.

By the way, I have no problem with *adopt* as your verb. From NOAD:

> **adopt** (*v.*) take up or start to use or follow (an idea, method, or course of action): *this approach has been adopted by many big banks*.

One other thought: is 10 people a lot, or a few? If there were 20 people in the office, that's half the office! If you made your presentation to 200 people, though, that's a smaller percentage of converts.

Assuming 10 represents a significant number, you could try something like:

> Use of software X **became prevalent** after I presented its effective use on Y-type projects.

Comment: The point about the percentage of converts is a good one. In my case, I wasn't expected to do the presentation, and wasn't even remotely associated with that software. However, I had a great amount of experience with it, and wanted others to benefit as well. In that sense, my work was essentially an "extra achievement". Nonetheless, future readers of this Q&A will likely face this situation too, and that is an important point to consider.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many...let me list down here a few of them.

> Presented on the use of software X on Y-type projects so effectively that 10 people started using it then. 
>  My presentation on the use of software X on Y-type projects made 10 people using it. 
>   My presentation convinced 10 people to use software X on Y-type projects. 
>   My presentation simply turned 10 attendees into customers! *(-I'll use this to impress others if software is commercial or else simply replace *customers* with *users*)*.

And there could be many...